# Hammer.js cannot get swipe working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, hammer.js

I'm trying to put together a simple example of hammer.js. It seems like a cool library but I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I expect the box to move by 10px each time I swipe it either left or right. I'm clearly making a simple mistake but just cannot see it. Please help.

example here http://jsfiddle.net/4z5uL/

I have tested it on many devices and browsers and just cannot get it working.

also just to point out I have included this viewport in my website.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was the swipe action could not be captured on such a small element. I added swipe to the document instead and that worked.

Any suggestions for better use would be great.

It also appears that hammerjs doesn't support ie9 mobile on windows7.8